# Get the first n lines matching a certain pattern (with Linux commands)

Tags: linux, grep

I have a giant file where I want to find a term *model*.  I want to pipe the first 5 lines containing the word *model* to another file. How do I do that using Linux commands?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`man grep` mentions that

```
 -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.  If the  input  is
          standard  input  from a regular file, and NUM matching lines are
          output, grep ensures that the standard input  is  positioned  to
          just  after the last matching line before exiting, regardless of
          the presence of trailing context lines.  This enables a  calling
          process  to resume a search.
```

so one can use

```
grep model old_file_name.txt -m 5 > new_file_name.txt
```

No need for a pipe. grep supports almost everything you need on it's own.

Answer (score 7):

```
grep model [file] | head -n 5 > [newfile]
```

Answer (score 2):

grep "model" filename | head -n 5 > newfile

Answer (score -1):

```
cat file | grep model | head -n 5 > outfile.txt
```

Comment: This is horrific, using `cat` will load the whole file into memory first before running `grep` . Just call `grep` with a file parameter.

Comment: The other answers are better, but the above comment is not true.  The shell will start all 3 commands without waiting for any output first.

Comment: On Windows, pipes are available on the command line, but the deal is that the first program is run and written to a file. Then, the next program is run on those results. That's not how Linux/Unix works. Unix isn't that brain damaged. And neither reads the whole file into memory first. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: I've been piping [z]cat to grep for many years, and I'm a creature of habit. That said, the poster did say "a giant file" and there is plenty of evidence that avoiding the call to cat can save significant time in that case

Comment: @smalloy, how would cat "save significant time"?  On my system, head(1) exits when it is done, and then cat(1) harmlessly terminates from a SIGPIPE having read only the beginning of its input.

Comment: To memory, or to file, either will result in a significant time expenditure that results in no net gain